# For a given hive query, how to trace/link Hive metastore logs

Tags: hive, hive-metastore

I am getting MySQL alerts for some slow queries. So, I want to trace back the Hive query which is responsible for this?

Hive Stack is like:  MySQL -> HMS(Hive Metadata Service) -> HS2 server -> beeline
Now, each component is logging queries being executed by it but I am not able to find a traceId sort of value which can link all these executed queries by different components.

For HS2 server and beeline, I am getting a queryId like

- in beeline

```
INFO  : Compiling command(queryId=hadoop_20221109165616_c873bba7-b6e1-4ba0-a92f-b46c5f76ca36): use test
```

- and in HS2

```
2022-11-09T16:56:16,429 INFO  [180b5b91-eea3-47a9-a16f-1bf6c49d438a HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-125]: ql.Driver (Driver.java:compile(409)) - Compiling command(queryId=hadoop_20221109165616_c873bba7-b6e1-4ba0-a92f-b46c5f76ca36): use test
```

but nothing sort of this in hive metastore logs.
Is there a way to get this sort of traceId or queryId in HMS logs, so that my object of tracing a hive query in all hive services can be achieved?